# Android onBackPressed doesn't change layout to previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I got an application with a single activity which has a `LinearLayout` which is a container for fragments.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Up until now I switched between fragments in the container with no problem. Now I needed to add a switch of a fragment with another which has the same layout but with a different logic.

Here is how I switch between the fragments:

```
final MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    final Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("key", "value");
    fragment .setArguments(args);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out).replace(R.id.container, fragment );
    if(addToBackStack)
    {
        transaction.addToBackStack(tag).commit();
    }
    else
    {
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

When switching between the 2 fragments, I pass false as the `addToBackStack` so the calling fragment with the same layout won't be saved to the back stack.

The switch itself works, but when I press the back button, I see that the action bar's title is changing to the previous title and the previous fragment's `onCreateView` is called, but the layout itself remains the same and not changing. Why is that?

Comment: Could you share MyFrgment class code?

Comment: It's pretty big.. some specific part?

Comment: onCreateView  and onCreate